# VBA Bubble Graph

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have four columns made of several rows. Some are full of informations some are empty as showed below.

```
 w     x     y   z
Blue   23   74   120
White  50   25   34
Grey   11   45   
Yellow 25   12   12
Black  11   22
```

What I am trying to do is to have each row representing a 'bubble' in a bubble excel graph. The size of the bubble wil be equal to z. 
Thanks to  Tom Hollander I found a way to manage it, I tweaked the code to make what I was looking for, find below Tom's one.Here each bubble represent a serie so have its own label. My only issue right now is, I want to tell my code to do not create a bubble, and i.e do not create a label, when the Z axis is empty.

Any idea?

I am also trying to find a way for the label order follow the bubble order, i.e the highest bubble will have it label first etc...

```
Public Sub CreateMultiSeriesBubbleChart()
    If (selection.Columns.Count <> 4 Or selection.Rows.Count < 3) Then
        MsgBox "Selection must have 4 columns and at least 2 rows"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim bubbleChart As ChartObject
    Set bubbleChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=selection.Left, 
Width:=600, Top:=selection.Top, Height:=400)
    bubbleChart.chart.ChartType = xlBubble
    Dim r As Integer
    For r = 2 To selection.Rows.Count
        With bubbleChart.chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .Name = "=" & selection.Cells(r, 1).Address(External:=True)
            .XValues = selection.Cells(r, 2).Address(External:=True)
            .Values = selection.Cells(r, 3).Address(External:=True)
            .BubbleSizes = selection.Cells(r, 4).Address(External:=True)
        End With

    Next

    bubbleChart.chart.SetElement 
(msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
    bubbleChart.chart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "=" & 
selection.Cells(1, 2).Address(External:=True)

    bubbleChart.chart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleRotated)
    bubbleChart.chart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "=" & 
selection.Cells(1, 3).Address(External:=True)

    bubbleChart.chart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryGridLinesMajor)
    bubbleChart.chart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 0
End Sub
```

Thank you very much for any coments or help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add if statement.

```
Public Sub CreateMultiSeriesBubbleChart()
    If (Selection.Columns.Count <> 4 Or Selection.Rows.Count < 3) Then
        MsgBox "Selection must have 4 columns and at least 2 rows"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim bubbleChart As ChartObject
    Set bubbleChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=Selection.Left, Width:=600, Top:=Selection.Top, Height:=400)
    bubbleChart.Chart.ChartType = xlBubble
    Dim r As Integer
    For r = 2 To Selection.Rows.Count
        If Selection.Cells(r, 4) <> "" Then '<~~ z is not empty
            With bubbleChart.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                .Name = "=" & Selection.Cells(r, 1).Address(External:=True)
                .XValues = Selection.Cells(r, 2).Address(External:=True)
                .Values = Selection.Cells(r, 3).Address(External:=True)
                .BubbleSizes = Selection.Cells(r, 4).Address(External:=True)
            End With
        End If
    Next

    bubbleChart.Chart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
    bubbleChart.Chart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "=" & Selection.Cells(1, 2).Address(External:=True)

    bubbleChart.Chart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleRotated)
    bubbleChart.Chart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "=" & Selection.Cells(1, 3).Address(External:=True)

    bubbleChart.Chart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryGridLinesMajor)
    bubbleChart.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 0
End Sub
```